# Is my foundation design for this garbage can hutch overcomplicated?

Tags: framing, deck, foundation

I am looking for feedback on the plan for a hutch I want to build for my garbage cans and table saw. I plan to have it sit on a slope next to my driveway. I’ve used a deck planning tool to guess at what size all of the lumber should be but expect I am making a bunch of amateur mistakes.

Here’s some photos of the site:

[image]

[image]

The fence is where I’d like the hutch to sit flush to. I'll be tearing it out.

Here’s a mockup of kind of roughly the idea:

[image]

[image]

(I ran into some surprises with how I’ll have to deal with the roof so I left the wall outline unfinished, but you get the idea).

Here’s a few pics of what I think the foundation will look like:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I didn’t draw it in but I plan to have all the posts in concrete. Dims are approx 6 ft wide at the widest point, 4.5 ft tall (once framed) and approx 9 ft long.

([Album with all pics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYjVF.jpg))

The beams are 2x10, and I think it’s OK to use 2x4 for the joists since they’re spanning less than 5 ft 8”. I was planning on using strong ties for all the connections (post to beam, joist to beam).

Is there an easier way to do the end that sits flush with the ground? Right now the plan would mean I have to dig down quite a bit to make room both for the beam and the posts. Is there another way I should be doing this that requires less digging?

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. You've done well providing all the pics, but you haven't given any dimensions at all. It's hard to imagine that a "garbage can hutch" is going to be all that huge, so my guess is that 2x10 are going to be massively oversized, but give us some dimensions to work with. Also, you've got way too many questions all in one. Pick one question (and possibly a closely related follow up) at a time - that's how we roll 'round here (as at all SE sites). You'll get some great advice, just hang out...

Comment: I agree with FreeMan, and also note that one doesn't usually fit joists to the ground. You'd excavate the area where the framing will reside and keep the lumber square. I'd just use concrete "cookies" or deck blocks on the ground. Unless you have a high wind concern, footings poured in the ground are excessive, in my opinion.

Comment: Still a bit light on details, but in general I think you'd be fine. I still think a 2x10 is overkill for the rim joist, but it certainly won't _hurt_. Remembering that this is just for storing garbage cans, the major concern would be "what happens if this fails and slides down hill"? If it's not going to hit anything significant (and it shouldn't if you're actually digging footers), go for it!

Comment: Thanks all. Are there other details that would be helpful?

What's the minimum beam size that would be OK for this application? Can I get away with 2x6? 

FWIW, I am planning on putting a (fairly heavy, RIDGID cast-iron top) table saw in there as well.